Blender deform object in one direction with smooth cutoff
So, simply put I have this somewhat decimated but still high-poly mesh that I wanted to deform at the bottom of it, I have tried the simple deform modifier with every setting and pivot but I'm not really getting the results, I want to keep the rest of the object above the line unchanged while tucking in the bottom part, I need to figure this out somehow.


Hello, maybe try with the Pose brush in Sculpt mode?

oh thanks, i'll try that. first i was thinking about using an armature to see if it works

yes you can also try with an armature
